# Why give this "cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: java, class

I use Eclipse for java programming. I no understand why it gives cannot resolved for (myBox1.width = 10;) to a variable my sample code in below

```
class Boxf {
   double width;
   double height;
   double depth;

} 


class BoxDemo2 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Boxf mybBox1 = new Boxf();
       Boxf mybBox2 = new Boxf();
       double vol;

       myBox1.width = 10;
       myBox1.height = 20.90;
       myBox1.depth = 15.75;
       vol = myBox1.width * myBox1.height * myBox1.depth;

    System.out.println("Volume1 is = "+ vol);

    myBox2.width= 10;
    myBox2.height = 20.90;
    myBox2.depth = 15.75;
    vol = myBox2.width * myBox2.height * myBox2.depth;
    System.out.println("Volume2 is = "+ vol);
   }
```

Comment: Its mybBox1 and not myBox1, notice the small b in names

Comment: Welcome to stack (downvotes) overflow... (I didn't downvote). Typos are not forgiven here so make sure you don't have any before typing a question... Learned that the hard way.

Answer (score 2):

Because your instances are `mybBox1` (and `mybBox2`) not `myBox1` (and `myBox2`). The easiest solution I can see is to change this

```
Boxf mybBox1 = new Boxf();
Boxf mybBox2 = new Boxf();
```

to

```
Boxf myBox1 = new Boxf();
Boxf myBox2 = new Boxf();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing same thing without using constructor

```
   myBox1.width = 10;
   myBox1.height = 20.90;
   myBox1.depth = 15.75;
   vol = myBox1.width * myBox1.height * myBox1.depth;
```

u can do the same thing with this code

```
  public void sample ( double width ,double height ,double depth)
    {
    this.width=width;
    this.height=height;
    this.depth=depth;
    }
```

After this with the help of object u can access values such that

```
mybox1.sample(10,20.90,15.75);
mybox2.sample(10,20.90,15.75);
```

With the help of this pointer u can calculate the volume of box1,box2 . Try this code it will definitely work ...........